# Setting state in a component but changing only the second element in a list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a battleShip game using React.

I have a state like this inside my component, every coordinate has a list with two 'states', 'empty' if there is not a ship ('busy' if there is) in it and 'intact' the coordinate hasn't been hit ('hit' if it has).

```
this.state = {
  status: {
    A1: ['empty', 'intact'],
    B1: ['busy', 'intact']
  }
}
```

What I want to do is: When I click in a coord in the battleShip grid to shoot it, **I want to set only the second element in the list to 'hit' and leave the first element without changes**.

Something like this:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
  const coord = e.target.id; //get the coord from the element clicked, like 'A1'
  this.setState({ status: { coord[1]: 'hit' } });       
}
```

So I want my new State to be :

```
this.state = {
  status: {
    A1: ['empty', 'hit'],
    B1: ['busy', 'intact']
  }
}
```

How do I write `this.setState({ status: { coord[1]: 'hit' } })` in the correct way, so that my new State is exactly like above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct modification of state arrays in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use property accessors and slice for this.

For example:

```js
handleClick = (e) => {
    const coord = e.target.id; //get the coord from the element clicked, like 'A1'
    const current = this.state.status[coord];
    let newVal = current.slice(); // Clone array
    newVal[1] = 'hit';
    this.setState({ status: { ...this.state.status, [coord]: newVal } });
};
```

That is assuming `e.target.value` is a string.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) is the documentation on property accessors from MDN.

Comment: thank you, it worked perfectly! a elegant solution as well!

Answer (score 1):

```
let newStatus = {...this.state.status};
newStatus.A1[1] = 'hit';
this.setState({status: newStatus});
```

Comment: This will mutate the `A1` array. `newStatus.A1 = [newStatus.A1[0], 'hit'];` should work.

Comment: Is it a problem to mutate the copied object's array?

Comment: Yes, in this case with arrays. Had `this.state.status` only contained keys with string values, it would have been fine. Try `const a = [1]; const s1 = { a }; const s2 = {...s1}; s1.a === s2.a` and you will see it's still the same array.